# Webpack don't rebuild bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have some troubles with webpack. I'm using ES6, ReactJS, Mobx and SASS. Here is my development config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

var pathes = {
  root: './src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/static',
  entry: './src/main/javascript/client.js',
  js:  '/js/',
  css: '/css/'
}

var extractSASS = new ExtractTextPlugin( path.join(pathes.css, 'main.css') );
var extractVendorCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin( path.join(pathes.css, 'vendor.css') );

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  entry: pathes.entry,
  output: {
    path: pathes.root,
    filename: path.join(pathes.js, 'app.js')
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loaders: [ 'babel' ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: extractSASS.extract([ 'css', 'postcss', 'sass' ])
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: extractVendorCSS.extract([ 'css' ])
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    extractSASS,
    extractVendorCSS,
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      DEVELOPMENT: true
    })
  ],
  postcss: function () {
    return [ autoprefixer ];
  }
};
```

All was good, but today I add interceptor for redirection to `/index` on server-side Spring boot application. I have no idea how this could break webpack, but he stopped to rebuild the bundle. 
To run webpack I use this command:

```
webpack --progress --colors --watch --config ./configs/webpack.development.config.js
```

I don't use webpack-dev-server, because static files are served by embedded Tomcat (Spring boot).

In console webpack said that bundle was rebuilded, but bundle does not contains any changes.

An interesting detail is that if I change the bundle name from `app.js` to for example `app1.js` and re-run webpack by command above, webpack will take all changes and the bundle will be updated. After that webpack will automatically rebuild the bundle by for ane changes (because `--watch`).

Why webpack don't rebuild the bundle with old name `app.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your console shows that the files have been rebuilt and you're not seeing the changes, chances are the files are cached by your browser.

Try adding some kind of cache-busting parameter to wherever you are including them:

```
<script src="app.js?<% time.now() %>"></script>
```

This is fine for development, but for production, you might want to look at using the [assets-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/assets-webpack-plugin)